# Consequences of Hahn Banach Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a normed vector space over $\mathbb{C}$

Let $U \subset V$ be a subspace of $V$

Let $p : V \to \mathbb{R}$ be a seminorm

Let $f : U \to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous linear functional such that $\forall u \in U: |f(u)| \leq p(u)$

I would like to know if is it true that exist a continuous linear functional $F : V \to \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$
\forall u \in U: f(u) = F(u)
$$
$$
\forall v \in V: |F(v)| \leq p(v)
$$
$$
||F||=||f||
$$
Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is. In many books you can find it.

Comment: @Piquito can you suggest any to me?

Comment: Look at the COMMENT below, please.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-See at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem where the first "important consequence" is what you need and where you have a bibliography in English. In many books this consequence is the theorem itself. For example in the attached figure (a french source; the proof is not easy at all for a beginner).

[image]

Comment: thanks @Piquito but the theorem you showed me isn't what i need beacause it's not include the seminorm $p$ in my assumptions, all of three assumptions i require